# zeromq.js monitoring events sending identity

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I'm using the latest build of **`zeromq.js`** and trying to add an event listener on `accept`-event as such:

```
socket.on( 'accept',
            function( ...args ) { console.log( 'accept, endpoint:', args ); }
            );
```

The event triggers this output:

```
accept [ 37, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:5559', undefined ]
```

I'm using a **`DEALER/ROUTER`** formal archetype pattern, however the issue seems to be common amongst all socket types.

Shouldn't the first parameter be the specified **`.identify`** of the socket, since it's defined before the **`.connect()`** method is going to be called?

I.e.:

```
this.socket = zmq.socket( 'dealer' );
this.socket.identity = this.id;
this.socket.connect( "tcp://${this.config.socket.host}:${this.config.socket.port}" );
```

`this.id` is a string such as `resolver-83749`

I need to manage my socket connections and reference them for forwarding control purposes. If a socket connects and disconnects I need to be able to map the connection.

Thanks and happy holidays everyone!